# Date Format Woocommerce input date field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi im trying to change my date format of woocommerce date input field (wordpress) but nothing seems to work. Ive tried two different approaches .

1st one ( functions.php )

```
    // Ajout de input pour date de naissance dans checkout
function date_naissance_field( $fields ) {
    // Ajouter un champ de date de naissance aux champs de facturation
    $fields['billing']['date_naissance'] = array(
        'type'        => 'date', // Type de champ 
        'label'       => __( 'Date de naissance'), // Label et placeholder
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide', 'date_naissance' ), // Classe CSS
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true, // Effacer le champ après validation
        'autocomplete' => 'off', // Désactiver l'autocomplétion
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy', // Format personnalisé
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'date_naissance_field' );
```

2nd Approach i tried was ( functions.php)

```
function date_naissance_field( $fields ) {
    // Ajouter un champ de date de naissance aux champs de facturation
    $fields['billing']['date_naissance'] = array(
        'type'        => 'date', // Type de champ 
        'label'       => __( 'Date de naissance'), // Label et placeholder
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide', 'date_naissance' ), // Classe CSS
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true, // Effacer le champ après validation
        'autocomplete' => 'off', // Désactiver l'autocomplétion
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm', // Format personnalisé
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'date_naissance_field' );

// Enqueue custom JavaScript for Datepicker initialization
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-datepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-datepicker.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts' );
```

and my javascript file

```
  (function($) {
  $(function() {
    $("#date_naissance").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Seems ok to me. What format is returning ? Also you can set date format from WP settings

Comment: its still returning mm/dd/yyyy .. If i set the date format from WP setting will it affect my woocommerce input fields as well ?